# Функция из рекурсии

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять какой аргумент нужно передать функции для того чтобы рекурсия заработала. Пробовал передавать словарь, список, любое имя передавал, а ошибка пишет данное имя не определено. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот 2 отдельных друг от друга фрагмента кода:

```
def look_for_key(box):  # Рекурсия
    for item in box:
        if item.is_a_box(): 
            look_for_key(item)
        elif item.is_a_key():
            print('Found the key')


def look_for_key(main_box):  # Ищем ключ
    pile = main_box.make_a_pile_to_look_throught()
    while pile is not empty:
        box = pile.grab_a_box()
        for item in box:
            if item.is_a_box():
                pile.append(item)
            elif item.is_a_key():
                print('Found thr key')
```

Comment: Какое имя не определено? Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Плохая идея использовать одно и тоже имя функции, т.к. вторая функция перепишет собой первую и всегда будет вызываться `def look_for_key(main_box)`

Comment: Например если делаю вызов для второй функции 
`look_for_key(Коробка)` вывод: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Евгений/PycharmProjects/untitled/example1.py", line 11, in <module>
    look_for_key(Коробка)
NameError: name 'Коробка' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1`. Такой же вывод и для первой функции.

Comment: Приведены в вопросе 2 отдельные друг от друга функции. Я же написал, что вот 2 фрагмента кода.

Comment: Эти функции я переписал из книги "Грокаем алгоритмы", для того чтобы посмотреть как они работают.

Answer (score 1):

Я вроде понял. `main_box`, `make_a_pile_to_look_throught()`, `grab_a_box()`, `is_a_box()`, `is_a_key()`, `box` - это ведь оказывается должны быть предыдущие функции, это же должно быть рекурсией. Ведь нужно от чего-то отталкиваться. Я извиняюсь, что предложил данные 2 не полных кода. Я просто поспешил их сразу выполнять.

Comment: Только скажите прав ли я или нет? А то я уже сам начинаю сомневаться

Comment: Естественно. К тому же вы пытаетесь вызывать функцию как `look_for_key(Коробка)`, а Коробка с точки зрения Python - это имя переменной. Если вы в эту переменную ничего не записали, то будет ошибка `NameError`.